# kernel device driver or userspace program

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm currently using a SAMA5D31-EK board running Linux 3.10.0+ to control some hardware devices. I'm using GPIOs, I2C, PWM and UARTS available in that board. Some devices are controlled with just a GPIO line while others need an UART a PWM and 3 GPIOs. So far I'm using an userspace program to control those hardware devices - basically a stepper motor, an ADC and a alphanumeric LCD display.

What would be the advantges of developping a kernel device driver to control those devices? So far (using a userspace program) the only limitation I've found is speed: since I have to bit bang some GPIOs, the result is a bit slow.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have the platform-specific drivers available for the I2C/GPIO/PWM/UART interfaces on your board(it should be part of BSP[Board-support-package] ).

It is just that you don't want to use the Kernel device driver framework and want to do things from the user-space. I'd been in this situation hence I know, how tempting it could be,especially , if you are not well-versed in Kernel device drivers.

a. **SPEED**:  You mentioned it. But, you probably didn't grasp the reason completely.

Speed efficiency comes from avoiding the Context-switching between Kernel and User-space process. Here is an example:

```
/* A loop in kernel code which reads a register 100 time */
for (i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ )
{
  __kernel_read_reg(...);
}

/* A loop in User-space code which reads a register 100 time */
for ( i= 0 ; i < 100; i++)
{
   __user_read_reg(...);
}
```

Functionality wise both *_read_reg() is same. Assuming that __user_read_reg() will go through a typical-system-call procedure,it has to do a Context-switch for every single __user_read_reg(...) which is too costly.

You may argue, "We can mmap() the hardware registers and avoid system call for such operations".
Of course, you could do that, but the point I was making is:
What is close to hardware (for example: a register read or write or handling an interrupt) should be done as fast as possible. Latencies involved in context-switching will impact the performance.

b. **Existing/Tested/Well-built subsystems:**

If you see an I2C subsystem in the Linux Kernel, it provides a well-tested, robust framework which could be easily-reused. You don't have to write full I2C subsytem (handling all device types, speed, various configuration etc ) in the user-space.
Re-using" what is already done could be one big advantage while going for kernel device drivers.

c. **Move from Polling-based approach to Interrupt-based mechanism**

If you are not handling interrupts in Kernel driver,You must be using some sort of polling-mechanism in the user-space process. Depending on the system, it might not be very reliable way of handling the hardware-changes.Definitely not accurate/reliable for fast devices.

Interrupt-based mechanism , in general, where you handle the critical changes as fast as possible( Hardware interrupt context) and move the non-critical work-load either to user-space or some other kernel mechanism is more reliable way of handling devices.

Of-course, there could be several more arguments and counter-arguments besides above three.

Another thread which might be of interest to you is here:
[Userspace vs kernel space driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286772/userspace-vs-kernel-space-driver?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

There are generic userspace driver subsystem available in kernel: *Userspace IO
drivers*.

The logic of controlling the device does not necessarily have to be within the kernel, as the device does not need to take advantage of any of other resources that the kernel provides.

So Userspace drivers are simple drivers which enable just memory access to device registers and servicing interrupts.

You say you are using userspace programs to control UART, GPIO, I2C, PWM?

There are already kernel drivers in kernel for those subsystems, so it may be
that your userspace programs are already using kernel drivers for those subsystems.